# PHP If Fields Are Not Populated Not Working Correctly

Tags: php

I have a form that I request details on that I wish to make sure that at the bare minimum they populate their car reg, dob, postcode and at least 3 bits of driving information.

I then return an ID to them from my web service to state what their ID is and this is submitted to my database in azure.

I am most certainly not a PHP man, and for some reason my code doesn't appear to be working as I can send information without populating all of the fields.

Can someone spot where I am going wrong, I literally knocked this up with no prior PHP knowledge and I'm surprised I got this far.

My Code:

```
<?php

if($_POST['pcode_txtbx'] != "" || $_POST['dob_txtbx'] != "" || $_POST['carreg_txtbx'] != "" || $_POST['drvn_txtbx0'] != "" || $_POST['dln_txtbx0'] != "" || $_POST['dlc_code_txtbx0'] != "") : 

// ALWAYS RAISE THE PHP ERROR REPORTING TO THE HIGHEST POSSIBLE LEVEL
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// SHOW THE REQUEST VARIABLES 
//var_dump($_POST);

// CONSTRUCT THE QUERY STRING
$data = 
[ 'PCode'         => $_POST['pcode_txtbx']
, 'CarReg'      => $_POST['carreg_txtbx']
, 'DateofBirth'      => $_POST['dob_txtbx']
, 'Driver0'            => $_POST['drvn_txtbx0']
, 'DLN0'           => $_POST['dln_txtbx0']
, 'CheckCode0'            => $_POST['dlc_code_txtbx0']
, 'Driver1'            => $_POST['drvn_txtbx1']
, 'DLN1'           => $_POST['dln_txtbx1']
, 'CheckCode1'            => $_POST['dlc_code_txtbx1']
, 'Driver2'            => $_POST['drvn_txtbx2']
, 'DLN2'           => $_POST['dln_txtbx2']
, 'CheckCode2'            => $_POST['dlc_code_txtbx2']
, 'Driver3'            => $_POST['drvn_txtbx3']
, 'DLN3'           => $_POST['dln_txtbx3']
, 'CheckCode3'            => $_POST['dlc_code_txtbx3']
, 'Driver4'            => $_POST['drvn_txtbx4']
, 'DLN4'           => $_POST['dln_txtbx4']
, 'CheckCode4'            => $_POST['dlc_code_txtbx4']
];

// CONSTRUCT THE URL
$url = 'http://mywebservice/myservice.svc?' . http_build_query($data);

?>
<br><center>
&nbsp; Thank you for submitting your Code to us, your submission reference is: 
<br><br>
<b>
<?php 
// TRY THE WEB SERVICE
$htm = my_curl($url);

else :
?>
</b>
<br><br><center>
&nbsp; Please make sure you have the Postcode, Car Registration, Date of Birth and at least the top most Driver Details filled in! 
<br><br>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">Go Back and Try Again</a>
</center>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically if any of the fields in that first IF statement are blank it should not be submitting to the server, where have I gone wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Use the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php) function instead of `$_POST['something'] != ""`. You test only if the variable contains something, but not if the variable exist.

Comment: Also, take a look at [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: As is you would always be able to submit your form. As php runs on the server, only after receiving the form post your php would be able to check if there was a value in each form field...
If you want to prevent the from from being posted you will have to add some sort of javascript validation which runs on the client (browser) and could prevent the form from being submited.

Comment: @FirstOne - That's hit the spot bang on, a combination of yours and geggleto 's answers have resolved that for me.

Thank you Gentlemen and thank you everybody else for the input, appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are also using || which is OR ... 
so your logic reads like..... 
if a is not empty string OR if b is not empty string OR c is not empty string...

What you want is AND. 
if a is not an empty string AND b is not... and c is not .. then submit to the server.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 issues here:

1. you use OR instead of AND
2. you assume that all variables come in POST which is no necessarilly true.

I suggest you use the following condition:

> if(!empty($_POST['pcode_txtbx']) && !empty($_POST['dob_txtbx']) &&  ...// 
>   same for other fields  )

Comment: No need to check if `isset` **AND** `empty` since `empty()` does that for you ^^.